# Why does my code not work after R restart?

Tags: r

I put together the below code yesterday and the output worked fine;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mydf <- data.frame( Category = c("Substitution - T1", 
                                 "Unwarranted low value transaction - T2", 
                                 "Overall Suspect Terminals"),
                    Nov_21=c(4, 5, 5),
                    Dec_21=c(16, 9, 16),
                    Jan_22=c(28, 13, 30))

mydf %>%
  mutate(Month = reorder(Month, row_number())) %>%
  mutate(Category = reorder(Category, row_number())) %>%
  gather(Month, Total, -Category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Total, fill = Category, group = Category)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Monthly Impacted Individual Terminals", subtitle = "3 Month View") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

I closed down R and my laptop. The next morning I restarted everything and tried to run the same code (highlight all code and run) but I get the below error;

```
Error in mutate(., Category = reorder(Category, row_number())) : 
  could not find function "mutate"
```

I remove the two lines of mutate code and re- run which then plots the graph as expected, I re-enter the two lines of mutate code to re-order my data and it doesn't work.

Why does my code work one day but without changing anything I encounter errors after restarting R?

Comment: You need to also load `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you @Sotos. Your advice solved my issue. Being new to R and for my future understanding - why does the code require ```dplyr``` when it worked without the previous day?

Comment: ```mutate``` is a ```dplyr``` function, maybe on the previous day you loaded the tidyverse package or another package that also loads in ```dplyr```?

Comment: @Omniswitcher - yes that is what I have done! Thank you, I will now know to look out for that.

Comment: I think it would be best if you removed the libraries called and call `library(tidyverse)`. It's a library that calls other libraries. It calls the libraries you've listed, needed, and if you're on this path, it probably includes libraries you will use in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Kat - much appreciated info.